# Передача в JSON 2-х масивов с сервера на клиент

Tags: javascript, java, json

Мне нужно передать из сервера на клиент 2 масива

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new Gson().toJson(
                    new Gson().toJson(calendarService.createMonthlyEvents(monthlyEventDto)) +
                            new Gson().toJson(calendarService.getDaysWerentCreated())));
```

Пробовал создать обьект на сервере, поставить каждому масиву в соответствие название:

```
new Gson.toJson("{ daysWhenCreated:" + 
    new Gson().toJson(calendarService.createMonthlyEvents(monthlyEventDto))) + 
        ", daysWhenNotCreated: " + 
    new Gson().toJson(calendarService.getDaysWerentCreated() + "}");
```

На клиента приходит строка типа json, пробую достать от туда 1 масив 
`result.daysWhenCreated` но получаю `undefined`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

**Update**

json строка на выходе получается такая:

```
"{
 [{"id":879,"name":"hhnefrd","startTime":"2016-12-‌​31T11:18:00","endT‌​ime":"2016-12-31T1‌​2:18:00","roomId"‌​:0,"description":​
"","recurrentId":‌​22,"color":"#1ba1‌​e2"}],
 ["30/1","3‌​1/1"]
 }"
```

Comment: Покажите строку json

Comment: "{[{\"id\":879,\"name\":\"hhnefrd\",\"startTime\":\"2016-12-31T11:18:00\",\"endTime\":\"2016-12-31T12:18:00\",\"roomId\":0,\"description\":\"\",\"recurrentId\":22,\"color\":\"#1ba1e2\"}],[\"30/1\",\"31/1\"]}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
    HashMap<String,ВашКласс> content = new HashMap<String,ВашКласс>();
    content.put("daysWhenCreated",calendarService.createMonthlyEvents(monthlyEventDto));
    content.put("daysWhenNotCreated",calendarService.getDaysWerentCreated());

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new Gson().toJson(content));
```

Должно быть верно.

Замените `ВашКласс` на возвращаемый тип в методах(Если он одинаков) или на Object если они разные.

---

Немного о том, что представлено в вашем вопросе:

- В первом примере вы складываете две строки с JSON'ом и результат выыглядит примерно так: `"{...}{...}"`, что не является валидным JSON'ом
- Во втором варианте Вы строку, которая является валидным JSON'ом, повторно пытаетесь привести к этому же виду.
- JSON строка, которую выы привели не соответствует ни первому, ни второму варианту (поскольку в первом случае он не валидный, а во втором должны присутствовать ключи:daysWhenCreated и daysWhenNotCreated)

Comment: @Ihor, не за что ;-) Если будут проблемы - пишите в комментарии.